# Can I make the QGIS feature display box larger?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.26. The box that contains the display info for features is quite small, and I have not been able to display anything in it that doesn't wrap around.

For instance, for IoT devices I'd like to display a URL to open a web page related to the device, and also display the time it was last seen. Both of those lines wrap.

Is there a way to make the display box larger?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot highlighting the box I'm asking about. It's the one made visible by the show map tips button on the button bar.

[image]

Comment: Could you specific which box you mean exactly, maybe with a screenshot?

Comment: If it is the identify form, it should be possible to create a custom form for it in the layer properties.